# Regex Validation not happening in Spring Boot Controller

Tags: java, regex, spring, spring-boot

```
@RequestMapping(value="apiInventory/apis",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public Map<String,Object> getData(@NotNull @Valid @RequestParam("host") String host,
        @NotNull @Valid @RequestParam("apiGroup") String basePath,
        @RequestParam(value="path",required=false) String path, 
        @RequestParam(value="version",required=false) String version, 
        @Valid @Pattern(regexp="get|post|put|delete|patch|options") @RequestParam(value="httpMethod",required=false) String httpMethod, 
        @RequestParam(value="includeAttributeDefinition",required=false, defaultValue="false") boolean includeAttributeDefinition) throws Exception{

          //My logic
        }
```

I have to ensure that the `httpMethod` takes in only the values of get,post,put,delete,patch,options

However, the validation isnt taking place. I was expecting an error but none was thrown when I sent an invalid `httpMethod`. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to annotate your controller class with "@Validated" in order to validation to work.

Answer (score 1):

Your regexp doesn't do what you think it does. You've surrounded the whole thing with square brackets `[]` turning it into a character class consisting of the characters `get|posudlachin`.

Try just removing the square brackets so the regexp is `get|post|put|delete|patch|options`.

You may also need to use the `@Valid` annotation for `httpMethod`.